# Создание своего типа

Tags: haskell

Подскажите, как создать следующий тип.

Необходима структура с 2 полями и конструктором, который принимает один аргумент.

**Пример:**

```
struct { String key; Bool modifKey; }
constr (String a) { парсинг строки и заполнение key и modifKey }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data MyType = MyType String Bool
constr s = MyType s False
```

Comment: Может, и так. А может, не совсем так. А может, совсем не так. Из вопроса ТС неясно, чего же он хочет.

Comment: ну, например:

     struct myType {
          string key;
          bool modifKey;

          myType(String a) {
               //Строка а типа "Shift+'e'"
               прасинг
               if (a содержит shift) { modifKey = True} else {modifKey = false}
               key = "e"
          } 
     }

Comment: Хм. Может, так?

     import Data.List (isInfixOf)
     data MyType = MyType String
     modifKey (MyType s) = "shift" `isInfixOf` s

Comment: А наглядней даже так:

    import Data.List (isInfixOf)
    data MyType = MyType {s::String}
    modifKey m = "shift" `isInfixOf` (s m)
    main = do
       print $ s m
       print $ modifKey m